# Inspecting zipped data seems to erase it

Tags: python, iterator

When I inspect my zipped data, it acts as if it has been erased. First, create zip object:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numbers_letters = zip(numbers, letters) 
print(list(numbers_letters))
```

As expected you see the list containing the tuples:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

But now:

```
print(list(numbers_letters))
```

returns an empty list. Where did my data go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `zip` returns an iterator in Python3.x. You can only iterate over an iterator once.

I suggest using:

```
print(list(zip(numbers, letters)))
```

> In simple terms, considering you have knowledge about pointers to
>   nodes in a linked list(C, C++), once you traverse through the list
>   using the head pointer, you can't use it again to start from the head.

Comment: There no way to reset it to start at the beginning again?

Comment: Nope. That's just not how it works. You'll need to call zip() again or store the iterator and make copies of it

Answer (score 2):

**Iterators are designed to generate data on the fly exactly one time, no more.**

By doing:

```
print(list(numbers_letters))
```

For the first time, you have exhausted the iterator. So, the second time there is nothing left to iterate!